# chosing between matrix theory and combinatroics

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, combinatorics, matrices

I have to take one more math course to finish my math minor , i am a computer science major and i want to know which course will benefit me more matrix theory or combinatorics and which takes more time to understand ?

I liked linear algebra a lot , i took two courses in linear algebra , and i also like graph theory from the algorithms classes that i took in computer science and i know combinatorics have to deal with graphs but i don't like permutations and these kind of stuff so i am really confused 
and is general topology useful for CS at all ?

i took a first course in real analysis and didn't really struggled alot and i have interest in geometry too

thanks alot

Comment: What is best for you depends on your other interests .... and you didnt tell us ...

Comment: Both of these fields are incredibly important in CS; but in somewhat different areas, without knowing which of these you wish to go into, we cannot really help much. If you want a good reference for combinatorics (and other interesting/useful maths) for CS you might want to check out Graham, Knuth and Patashnik's _Concrete Mathematics_.

Comment: Is it really impossible for you to just take both?

Comment: yes i just have to chose 1

Comment: Ask someone in your computer science faculty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably stay away from topology. It pops up occasionally in CS, but you have to seek it out more than it pops up.

Linear Algebra is incredibly useful. If you're interested in scientific computing or graphics programming, I'd say go for linear algebra. You literally can't much in scientific computing or numerical analysis without linear algebra. A lot of the cutting edge graphics and human-computer interaction research is very math intensive. My school has a virtual reality lab and does a ton of research in that area. You need vector math to deal with graphics at that level.

As for combinatorics, I can see why you may not like it. My first exposure to it in high school was rough. I didn't like it and didn't get it. I took a graph theory and combinatorics class a couple years ago, and I developed a much better intuition. Combinatorics is unlike other math courses in the way it trains your brain. Being able to "see" bijections is useful, and I found it helpful in attacking linear algebra. You also get useful tools like discrete probability and generating functions. If you're interested in pursuing topics like graph theory or discrete dynamical systems at a research level, combinatorics is a must. If you're rounding out your undergraduate degree and are moving onto industry afterwards, combinatorics is a nice thinking skillset. You won't appreciate the "train your brain" aspect until you're out of the course, most likely. Depending on where you apply, I've heard of combinatorics questions being asked as interview questions. Though these employers are on par of Facebook.

Hopefully this helps you make a better decision. Best of luck!

Comment: Topology also comes up in Functional Programming and Programming Language Semantics, which is more of what I was thinking of. I didn't even think about boundary representations. That's interesting and good to know!